Why did Smiley think of death here?
From John Le Carré's Smiley's People:

“Fine, thank you. How’s—” He struggled without success to remember the name of Lacon’s wife.


“Abandoned me, dammit. Ran off with her pesky riding instructor, blast her. Left me with the children. The girls are farmed out to boarding-schools, thank God.” Leaning over his hands, Lacon was staring up at the lightening sky. “Is that Orion up there, stuck like a golf ball between the chimney-pots?” he asked.


Which is another death, thought Smiley sadly, his mind staying briefly with Lacon’s broken marriage.

Is there any connection between the Orion and death? Or is it Lacon's comment about Orion that implies a sense of death? Or is the death just a symbolic one that refers to Lacon’s broken marriage? Not sure which one is the right interpretation, or if there's some other explanation.

I think Smiley views the broken marriage as a death, not Orion.

yes, Orion was killed by Scorpio and that's why they're next to each other in the night sky. Orion became a constellation after he died. Haven't read Smiley so I can't make the specific connection to the novel
